# Error: Cannot find module '@electron/packager/src/targets'

Tags: javascript, electron, node-modules, electron-packager, electron-forge

I installed @electron-forge/cli through

npm install --save-dev @electron-forge/cli

and when im trying to use it through

npx electron-forge

i am getting an error:

```
An unhandled exception has occurred inside Forge:
Cannot find module '@electron/packager/src/targets'
Require stack:
- /home/myName/myApp/node_modules/@electron-forge/core/dist/util/parse-archs.js
- /home/myName/myApp/node_modules/@electron-forge/core/dist/api/make.js
- /home/myName/myApp/node_modules/@electron-forge/core/dist/api/index.js
- /home/myName/myApp/node_modules/@electron-forge/cli/dist/util/check-system.js
- /home/myName/myApp/node_modules/@electron-forge/cli/dist/electron-forge.js
Error: Cannot find module '@electron/packager/src/targets'
Require stack:
- /home/myName/myApp/node_modules/@electron-forge/core/dist/util/parse-archs.js
- /home/myName/myApp/node_modules/@electron-forge/core/dist/api/make.js
- /home/myName/myApp/node_modules/@electron-forge/core/dist/api/index.js
- /home/myName/myApp/node_modules/@electron-forge/cli/dist/util/check-system.js
- /home/myName/myApp/node_modules/@electron-forge/cli/dist/electron-forge.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1039:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:885:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/myName/myApp/node_modules/@electron-forge/core/dist/util/parse-archs.js:5:51)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:19)
```

I tried redownloading electron and electron-forge, but still no solution

Comment: Found out the issue.
https://github.com/electron/forge/issues/3443